# Meaning of this sentence from Ulysses by Joyce

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I am not a native speaker and I fail to understand the meaning of the word "monks" (and even whether it is a noun or a verb) in the following quote, from the third chapter of [Proteus](http://m.joyceproject.com/chapters/proteus.html):

> The cords of all link back, strandentwining cable of all flesh. That
> is why mystic monks. Will you be as gods? Gaze in your omphalos.

Comment: See: https://www.bloomsandbarnacles.com/blog/2019/02/26/decoding-dedalus-omphalos

Comment: @user66974 Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user66974 That link doesn't explain the (strange) syntax of the 'monks' sentence. Can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: “*Though brief, the thought is quite dense and complicated. First, Stephen thinks of mystic monks trying to have an experience of the world itself. The whole mystical idea (in a nutshell) is that there is a certain experience that cannot be put into words, and after you have that experience you realize that up until then your existence had been quite superficial. It is as if there is an ideal metaphysical (fancy philosophical word meaning having to do with the nature of existence) world that most of us do not have access to.*” https://www.shmoop.com/ulysses-joyce/omphalos-pregnancy-symbol.html

Comment: "Mystic monks may gaze into their navels." So he's addressing them. Noun.

Comment: [literature.se] might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

> The cords of all link back, strandentwining cable of all flesh.

*Cords* alludes to *umbilical cords* (navelcords). The narrator's thoughts are flowing, driven by associations. That is, from **1)** midwife ⇒ **2)** stillbirth (misbirth) ⇒ **3)** trailing umbilical cord (Why? Because the narrator lost a son to miscarriage) ⇒ **4)** the mystical feeling of interconnectedness. (source - [Ulysses Annotated](https://www.ucpress.edu/book/9780520253971/ulysses-annotated))

> That is why mystic monks.

In other words, "*that is why mystic monks are fascinated by the navel and gaze at it in the discipline of contemplation*." (source - [Ulysses Annotated](https://www.ucpress.edu/book/9780520253971/ulysses-annotated))

> Will you be as gods?

From [Genesis 3:5](https://www.bibleref.com/Genesis/3/Genesis-3-5.html#:%7E:text=Genesis%203%3A5%2C%20NLT%3A,knowing%20both%20good%20and%20evil.), "For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall **be as gods**, knowing good and evil."

> omphalos

OED: "**1)** *A boss on a shield etc*. **2)** *A stone, in the temple of Apollo at Delphi, reputed to mark the central point of the earth*." Joyce is using it as a metaphor for *navel*.

---

No doubt someone will vote this answer down because they can't control themselves. Never mind them. Good luck with Ulysses!

Answer (score 0):

***monks*** is a noun here.

It's definition is:

> a member of a religious community of men typically living under vows of poverty, chastity, and obedience.

He is addressing the monks.

As mentioned [here](https://www.bloomsandbarnacles.com/blog/2019/02/26/decoding-dedalus-omphalos):

> Mystic monks may gaze into their navels

Comment: You have failed to correctly reference material written by others. [Please review our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: There seems to be a verb phrase missing. That is why mystic monks *do what*?